# Displaying two layers simultaneously by clicking button in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

How to display two layers simultaneously by clicking a button in openlayers3.

I want to display two layers simultaneously by clicking respective button, output should be displayed in a same map.

Answer (score 3):

Add a onclick handler to the button, and then in the handler call the addLayer method twice, one time for each layer.

Pseudocode:

```
var layer1 = new ...
var layer2 = new ...

var map = new ...

$(button).on('click', function() {
  map.addLayer(layer1);
  map.addLayer(layer2);
}
);
```